# How to display media (videos) from WP post in mobile app

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, wordpress, http

I am working in a mobile app where the users can visualize the posts from a specific WordPress account.

The issue I have so far, is that I can't display the media, only the pictures but not the videos

this is the plugin I am using http://wp-api.org/ and here are the [Docs for the media](http://wp-api.org/#media_get-attachments) but still I am unable to display the videos along the whole content.

[Here is a Plunker with what I have so far](http://plnkr.co/edit/BG72IgAmqsiDOPTFJsKR?p=preview), 
In the 3rd post with the title `Disfruta el video-set de Faceblind &#038; Melissa O en Nocturnal #6` is a video attached that you can't visualize due to the issue I am mentioning.

this is the html where you might see the `title` and the `excerpt` property of the `post`

```
<script id="tab-news.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
      <a ng-href="#/tabs/news/{{post.ID}}">
        <h2><span ng-bind-html="post.title"></span></h2>
        <p ng-bind-html="post.excerpt"></p>
        <p>{{:: post.date | date}}</p>
      </a>
    </div>
</script>
```

and here the one where you visualize the full `content` of the `post`

```
<script id="tab-post-detail.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Noticia">

      <h3>{{:: post.title}}</h3>
      <p ng-bind-html="post.content"></p>

  </ion-view>
</script>
```

and here is the Angular part

```
.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope,
                                 $ionicLoading,
                                 FreshlyPressed, $stateParams) {
  $scope.posts = [];
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    $scope.posts = FreshlyPressed.getBlogs($scope);
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
  }
  $scope.doRefresh();
})

.service('FreshlyPressed', function($http) {
  return {
    getBlogs: function($scope) {
      $scope.postsURL = 'http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts?_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK';
      $http.jsonp($scope.postsURL).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.posts = data;
      });
    },
    getPostById: function(postId) {
      var url ='http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/'+ postId;
      return $http.get(url);
    }
  }
})

.controller('PostDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, FreshlyPressed) {
  var postId = $stateParams.postId;
      console.log( $stateParams)
 FreshlyPressed.getPostById(postId).success(function(response){
    $scope.post = response;
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I played with your code and you're missing the [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service (Strict Contextual Escaping). Every time you embed some form of HTML you need to make sure Angular treats it as safe.

Add this to your controller:

```
.controller('PostDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $sce, FreshlyPressed) {

    var postId = $stateParams.postId,
    siteId = $stateParams.siteId;
    console.log( $stateParams);

    FreshlyPressed.getPostById(postId).success(function(response){
       console.log(response);
       $scope.post = response;
    });

    // Marks src as safe
    $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
       return $sce.trustAsHtml(src);
    };
});
```

In your view:

```
<ion-view view-title="Noticia">
  <ion-content has-header="true">
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item item-image text-center item-text-wrap padding">
        <h3 class="item-divider">{{:: post.title}}</h3>
        <p ng-bind-html="trustSrc(post.content)"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here's a working fork of your [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6H8GIaYvMrU8aP4UYxre?p=preview)

Comment: Gracias, Carlos, es usted muy amable.